# Putting the lines of a txt file in random order.

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I want to make a program where the lines of a .txt file get a random order.

This is my code thus far:

```
diction = {}
def selecteer_random_elftal():
    lijnen = open("bronmateriaal\\Spelers.txt").readlines()
    key = 0
    while lijnen != "":
        diction[key] = lijnen
        key =+ 1
    print("{0}: {1}".format(diction[key],diction[lijnen]))
selecteer_random_elftal()
```

When I do this, I get no outcome but I don't understand why?

Thanks for the help in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: `while lijnen != "":` - given that you don't change `linjen` inside the loop, this will either never start or never end. Given that `readlines` doesn't return a string, I'd say the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random%20shuffle#random.shuffle) and passing it a list of all the lines?

For example:

```
import random

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    lines = f_input.read().splitlines()
    random.shuffle(lines)
    print '\n'.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because lijnen is always not null, if your file is not empty.

Hence this condition `while lijnen != "":` will always equate to

```
while True:
```

Thus, your program will never come out of the while loop. So, no outcome!

Probably your system will ran out of resource (or something), if you leave the program running.